# Locating Default Static Block Content in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, static-block

I've made changes to the "Footer Links Company" static block in Magento 1.9.0.1 and need to revert back to the default content. How do I locate the original HTML that was in this block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable  `Template Path Hints` in your magento admin. so that you can track your location of phtml file that which are the loaded and from where. To enable that follow this **[link](http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/)**